# Recent Post Issue

Tags: posts

I have a personal site on WP where, I share short blog on IT subject.

Since 15 Jan 2020, I am having issue with recent post.  They are showing up on the site but not on the top of the page based on the date they are posted.  For example 4th Feb 2020 post should be on the top but they are down.  All my post show up under KB section menu within the site.

I reached out to hosting provider for help.  They told me to disable all the plugin and change the Theme to see, if the issue is resolved.  I tried and it did not.  They are unable to help me.

My question - Is it possible to edit WP page to fix post issue?  If so, I can login to hosting provider page with admin credentials and edit appropriate page and fix post issue.

My site structure is as follows:
Home
Services
Blog KB - This is where all the post are listed but they are not in proper date order.
Contact Us

My site page is www.infotechram.com

Thanks and look forward to your help.

Ram Lan

Comment: You mean here? http://www.infotechram.com/index.php/category/kbs/ I do see two February 4th posts at the top of the first page.

Comment: I can confirm what Rup said, I also see them on the homepage

Comment: It sounds like you might be cached. Have you tried clearing your browser cache, using a different browser, or using an Incognito window, while you're not logged in?

Comment: I was able to fix the issue with Post Re Order update plugin.  After that everything is working as per chronological order.